# extract all noun phrases from stanford parser output textfile using bash

Tags: bash, stanford-nlp

As a result of running Stanford Parser, I have output files contain a Penn Treebank structured
format. Each file contains the following.

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (S
      (NP
        (NP (DT The) (JJS strongest) (NN rain))
        (VP
          (ADVP (RB ever))
          (VBN recorded)
          (PP (IN in)
            (NP (NNP India)))))
      (VP
        (VP (VBD shut)
          (PRT (RP down))
          (NP
            (NP (DT the) (JJ financial) (NN hub))
            (PP (IN of)
              (NP (NNP Mumbai)))))
        (, ,)
        (VP (VBD snapped)
          (NP (NN communication) (NNS lines)))
        (, ,)
        (VP (VBD closed)
          (NP (NNS airports)))
        (CC and)
        (VP (VBD forced)
          (NP
            (NP (NNS thousands))
            (PP (IN of)
              (NP (NNS people))))
          (S
            (VP (TO to)
              (VP
                (VP (VB sleep)
                  (PP (IN in)
                    (NP (PRP$ their) (NNS offices))))
                (CC or)
                (VP (VB walk)
                  (NP (NN home))
                  (PP (IN during)
                    (NP (DT the) (NN night))))))))))
    (, ,)
    (NP (NNS officials))
    (VP (VBD said)
      (NP-TMP (NN today)))
    (. .)))
```

Now, I want to use a script in bash to extract all noun phrases using bash.  I know there is a way to implement what I want in Java. I am not sure how to figure out the way to work by reading a text file into a tree.

Comment: Do you require Bash-only specifically, or would it be okay to use standard Unix tools like Awk, `sed`, Perl, etc?  Then it's relatively easy, and relatively easy to find in Google.  What have you tried already?  What did you have trouble with?

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/ete2/tutorial/tutorial_trees.html

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/S-Expressions

Comment: Yes, I want to use standard tools such as awk, sed, etc. I made the above output text file into a single continous line. Then, I thought about using the paretheses but I am sure where the ending parethesis is. Without using the tree, I cannot find a relatively easy pattern where I can apply Unix/Linux script tools.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty Awk script to extract the outermost `NP` subtrees.  If you want the internals as well, you'll need a properly recursive solution.

```
awk -v RS='[ \t\n]+' '
    !np && /^\(NP$/ { np=paren }
    /^\(/ { ++paren }
    /\)/ { b=$0; c=""; while (sub(/\)$/, "", b)) {paren--; c=c ")"
        if (np && paren == np) {
            d=b; gsub(/\)+$/, "", d); print a " " d c; np=0; a=c="" } } }
    np { a=a (a ? " " : "") $0 }'
```

Answer (score 3):

Stanford provides another tool called tregex which operates on parse trees and will extract subtrees based on a query language similar to regular expressions.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex.shtml
http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html

This tool can be run from the command line.